# How good is the idea to do MBA after an MS

Tags: masters, graduation

I am currently in my senior year of engineering in Computer Engineering from India. I plan to do a Master of Science (preferably non-thesis) in the field of Computer Engineering from the US this fall. In fact, I've secured admission at the University of Illinois, Chicago. I, however, was planning to do an MBA in Finance directly after my Masters, or maybe after gaining some work experience after the Masters, since I also like finance. How good or bad is the idea?

Comment: Degrees are stepping stones, not final goals.  Why do you want an MBA?  For that matter, why do you want an MS in computer engineering?

Comment: Well. I want to do Computer Engineering because I'm interested in Microprocessors. I've been studying it since my eleventh grade, and I really want to know more about the modern processors. Likewise, I want to do an MBA because I love mathematics and accounts fascinate me. My dad and granddad are both into accounts, and I love it when they ask me to help them with balance sheets. I enjoy mathematical calculations. I may end up taking up computer hardware as a profession, but I really want to learn a lot about accounts.

Comment: @AyushKhemka: you won't necessarily "learn a lot about accounts" if you take an MBA. A professional course (as opposed to an academic one) might be better. As JeffE asks, why do you want an MBA? What good will it do you?

Comment: A modern US MBA has almost no math, so make sure you understand what the degree is actually for. It's not accounting, it's (at least in theory) mostly about being an effective manager.

Answer (score 2):

Both are very diverse field. A general advice, MS may be done without any industrial experience but MBA should be done only after working for a couple of years with proper industrial exposure.